# Auto-renewable/non-renewable subscription mac app

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase

I am new to Mac app development.
I want to add auto-renewable feature to my app.

Can anyone suggest me any links or documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best point to start from is:
https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf

And then:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267